# Search box in CSS3 not the right size

Tags: html, forms, css, webkit

I'm trying to make one of those pretty CSS3 search boxes based on the code from this site: http://speckyboy.com/2012/02/15/how-to-build-a-stylish-css3-search-box/

Everything looks like it does in the picture on that site except for the actual search box, which instead looks like this (in both Safari and Chrome):

[image: box]

Any help getting the search box to look the way it should?

UPDATE: Here is the code (you can also get this at the link above):

```
/* Form wrapper styling */
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

/* Form text input */

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}    

/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;
    outline: 0;   
}

.form-wrapper button:before { /* left arrow */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before,
.form-wrapper button:active:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}      

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner { /* remove extra button spacing for Mozilla Firefox */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: We'll need your code :) not just a picture of it!

Comment: Dump your code into a jsfiddle in addition to pasting it above so we can see it and edit it. Also, have you looked in ALL/other browsers? Are you using a CSS reset?

Comment: Looks like a padding issue in your CSS.

Comment: All of the code is at the link provided at the top. I'll add it to this post anyway though.

Comment: We don't want the code from the tutorial, we want the code you're using that isn't working. Please post your code in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I don't know what the code is that isn't working. New to this all. Sorry! :)

Comment: That's a nice tutorial! But where is **your** work?

Comment: Well I want to get the format working for the box, then I'll go ahead and edit the code. I'm not really sure what I am doing here. I usually do more back-end stuff, so I'm really new to CSS, especially more advanced stuff.

Comment: go on jsfiddle.net and put your code out there, and give us back the link to it so that we can help you figure out what's going on for you

Comment: [Where exactly are you going wrong?](http://jsfiddle.net/CVPfp/)

Comment: I'm not sure, on my site it looks like it does in my post, not like it does on JSFiddle.

Comment: @devirkahan could some of your websites css be conflicting with the search box css?

Comment: It's entirely possible, but I just tested it on a blank, fresh PHP file with no CSS imports and I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have into a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jN4ZT/1/ — It is working there, which is the weirdest thing. No idea...

Answer (score 0):

Box-sizing is your friend:

```
.font-wrapper input {
  ...
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```